# How to make list/detail help view equivalent in Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap

I want to create a medium height panel with a long list on its left side and a details section on the right.  This will be the help panel so that any unique command item selected from the left list will automatically display its description in the right hand side.  Details are in a xml file.  I've searched everything I know and searches which contain 'list' and 'bootstrap' in any permutation have not given fruit.  I cant find anything similar that I can re-write either.

[image]

Comment: is this better asked on StackOverflow?

Comment: @NKCampbell - I would say no as its a design/direction question and the people on stackoverflow are only answering quantifiable code questions and will slam this question for being to vague or that im asking them to do my homework and Ive lost a big chunk of my reputation on that before. Although perhaps your right that its on the wrong forum,  3 days and only 17 views later.

Comment: I think it's a fairly straightforward boostrap row / columns layout + javascript question imo. Not quite sure what you are looking for but here's a very quick and dirty example of how the html could layout - https://jsfiddle.net/nathankc/7ajped2n/ - I didn't stub out any javascript for you - hopefully this gets you started? - if this *is* a portion of what you are looking for the boostrap documentation on the GridSystem is helpful - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Comment: @NKCampbell  thank you very much indeed.  Please add this as an answer and I will agree it.  Thanks again